# Javascript - Empty string value returned for input text box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm trying to create a form where a user can select if they want emails about dogs and/or cats, select email or sms notifications, type in their email/phone #, then submit. I have everything down except for the email/phone #. No matter what I do I always get back an empty string for the value of the input text box.

I think the problem has something to do with me hiding the text box and the submit button on page load. I tried various ways of accessing the value of the text box such as accessing it directly within the event listener function, refreshing it with a variable and accessing value of that, etc. I thought I was on to something with the textbox_update function I added since I can now see what I'm typing reflected in the textbox_value variable, but I wasn't able to transfer that to the event listener function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.form');
let change = document.getElementById('change');
const input = document.querySelector(".send");

//input.addEventListener('change', smsORemail);
input.onchange = function() {
  smsORemail
};

function smsORemail() {
  let choice = form.notif.value;
  if (!choice) {
    return;
  }
  if (choice === 'email') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Email: ';
    const textbox = document.getElementById("textbox")
    textbox.style.display = "block";
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "john.smith@gmail.com";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
  } else if (choice === 'sms') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Phone: ';
    const textbox = document.getElementById("textbox")
    textbox.style.display = "block";
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "555-555-5555";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.getElementById("textbox").oninput = textbox_update;

function textbox_update() {
  let textbox_value = document.querySelector('input[name="comm_textbox"]').value;
  console.log(textbox_value)
  return textbox_value;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let textbox_value = textbox_update();
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  //console.log(formData.getAll('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_dog'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_cat'));
  console.log(formData.get('comm_textbox'));
  console.log(textbox_value);
})
```

```html
<form name="myform" onchange="smsORemail()" class="form">
  <p>Would you like notifications for new dogs and/or new cats?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="dog_checkbox" name="chk_dog" value="dogs"> Dogs<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_checkbox" name="chk_cat" value="cats"> Cats
  <br><br>

  <p>Would you like email or sms notifications?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="send" id="email_id" name="notif" value="email">
  <label for="email_id">E-mail</label>

  <input type="radio" class="send" id="sms_id" name="notif" value="sms">
  <label for="sms_id">SMS</label>
  <br><br>

  <label for="textbox" id="change" style="text-align: left; float: left;padding-right: 5px;"></label>
  <input type="text" name="comm_textbox" id="textbox" style="display: none;" placeholder="" value="">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" style="display: none;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Never call anything "submit" in a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several things,

I removed some functions that interfered with typing (`let textbox_value = textbox_update();`)

Added a delegated event handler for the radios

I also renamed the submit button since anything named submit in the form will interfere with a submit handler

Be consistent. Use addEventListener everywhere instead of "onevent" somewhere and eventlistener elsewhere

Toggling "hidden" is simpler than changing the display between block and none

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const change = document.getElementById('change');
const input = document.querySelector(".send");
const textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
const subbut = document.getElementById("subbut");

form.addEventListener('click', smsORemail);

function smsORemail(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[name=notif]")) return; 
  let choice = document.querySelector("input[name=notif]:checked")?.value || "";
  textbox.hidden=true;
  subbut.hidden= true;
  if (!choice) {
    return;
  }
  if (choice === 'email') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Email: ';
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "john.smith@gmail.com";
  } else if (choice === 'sms') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Phone: ';
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "555-555-5555";

  }
  subbut.hidden= false;
  textbox.hidden=false;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  //console.log(formData.getAll('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_dog'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_cat'));
  console.log(formData.get('comm_textbox'));
  console.log(textbox_value);
})
```

```html
<form name="myform" class="form">
  <p>Would you like notifications for new dogs and/or new cats?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="dog_checkbox" name="chk_dog" value="dogs"> Dogs<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_checkbox" name="chk_cat" value="cats"> Cats
  <br><br>

  <p>Would you like email or sms notifications?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="send" id="email_id" name="notif" value="email">
  <label for="email_id">E-mail</label>

  <input type="radio" class="send" id="sms_id" name="notif" value="sms">
  <label for="sms_id">SMS</label>
  <br><br>

  <label for="textbox" id="change" style="text-align: left; float: left;padding-right: 5px;"></label>
  <input type="text" name="comm_textbox" id="textbox" hidden placeholder="" value="">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="subbut" hidden>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically indeed it's because of your clean up Function, the function is being call on the onChange of the form declaration, and as you can see on this line

```
    textbox.value = "";
```

Will clear the textbox value, the problem lays in that, when you call it in the form's onchage event, any type of change, including the click of the submit will call the function and clear the values, before the click function is called.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Make your clean function run only by the radio buttons, no need for the call on the onChange line in the form declaration, so, just delete the first invoke in the onChange, and make sure the radioButton assignation is correct

e.g

1 - Remove the onChange() call in your html's first line

```
<form name="myform" class="form">
```

2 - Modify the radio button onChange assignment so it has '()' to trigger the function

```
input.onchange = function() {
  smsORemail()
};
```

Full Code:

```
<form name="myform" class="form">
  <p>Would you like notifications for new dogs and/or new cats?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="dog_checkbox" name="chk_dog" value="dogs"> Dogs<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_checkbox" name="chk_cat" value="cats"> Cats
  <br><br>

  <p>Would you like email or sms notifications?</p>
  <input type="radio" class="send" id="email_id" name="notif" value="email">
  <label for="email_id">E-mail</label>

  <input type="radio" class="send" id="sms_id" name="notif" value="sms">
  <label for="sms_id">SMS</label>
  <br><br>

  <label for="textbox" id="change" style="text-align: left; float: left;padding-right: 5px;"></label>
  <input type="text" name="comm_textbox" id="textbox" style="display: none;" placeholder="" value="">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" style="display: none;">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>let form = document.querySelector('.form');
let change = document.getElementById('change');
const input = document.querySelector(".send");

//input.addEventListener('change', smsORemail);
input.onchange = function() {
  smsORemail()
};

function smsORemail() {
  let choice = form.notif.value;
  if (!choice) {
    return;
  }
  if (choice === 'email') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Email: ';
    const textbox = document.getElementById("textbox")
    textbox.style.display = "block";
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "john.smith@gmail.com";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
  } else if (choice === 'sms') {
    change.innerHTML = 'Phone: ';
    const textbox = document.getElementById("textbox")
    textbox.style.display = "block";
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.placeholder = "555-555-5555";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.getElementById("textbox").oninput = textbox_update;

function textbox_update() {
  let textbox_value = document.querySelector('input[name="comm_textbox"]').value;
  console.log(textbox_value)
  return textbox_value;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let textbox_value = textbox_update();
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  //console.log(formData.getAll('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('notif'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_dog'));
  console.log(formData.get('chk_cat'));
  console.log(formData.get('comm_textbox'));
  console.log(textbox_value);
})
</script>
```